# Vue 3 component - trying to call AJAX

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I am trying to use Vue to make a bootstrap modal dynamic...

**Component HTML:**

```
 <div id="commentList">
     <comment-list
         v-for="comment in comments"
         :key="comment.id"
         :content="comment.content"
     ></comment-list>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
 const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
            return {
                comments: []
            };
        },
        created () {
            this.fetchComments();
        },
        methods: {
            fetchComments: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/activity/head/52',
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (data) {
                        this.comments = data;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    app.component('comment-list', {
        props: ['content'],
        delimiters: ['{:', ':}'],
        template:
            `
                <div class="row my-4">
                    <div class="col-1"><img src="/photo-alex.jpg" class="rounded-circle" style="width:38px; height: 38px"></div>
                    <div class="col-11 p-3 text-muted rounded bg-white border">
                        {:content:}
                    </div>
                </div>
            `
    });

    app.mount('#commentList');
</script>
```

The AJAX request isn't being executed, so that's the first issue I am encountering, thoughts?

AJAX response:

```
[
  {
    id: 76,
    ago: "in 4 hours",
    user: "Alex",
    content: "THIS IS A COMMENT"
  }
]
```

Comment: I've changed some code and fixed a few issues which were shown in console.log() the AJAX is now being called, but no errors in the console.log and no results are shown??? Ideas?

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] which would repro the issue. I suggest using codesanbox.io or similar. What you have ***should work***. Although this might be related to using Vue 2 syntax in Vue 3. Not yet versed in 3. Just to make sure, try using latest vue 2 instead of whatever version you're using.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I pasted from the wrong window initially...I had some simple errors caused by copy-paste from another window, which I also ran locally and didn't notice. The above is error free but also not working.

Comment: Nevermind, I spotted the issue. `this` in `fetchData` is not the Vue instace. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a normal function for `$ajax.success`. Inside it, `this` is that function's context, not the Vue instance. Change it to an arrow function so it has access to the outer scope, which will allow it to assign the response to the Vue instance's `comments`. Basically:

```js
fetchComments: function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/activity/head/52',
    method: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      this.comments = data;
    }
  });
}
```

Should become:

```js
fetchComments() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/activity/head/52',
    method: 'GET',
    success: data => {
      this.comments = data;
    }
  });
}
```

Note: changing from `fetchComments: function(){ ... }` to `fetchComments() { ... }` is irrelevant. They're the same thing, it's just I prefer the shorter syntax.

What matters is changing `success` from `function(data) { ... }` to `data => { ... }`.

Comment: Still not rendering the list...I feel it's the Vue3 requirement of data() having to be a function now???

Comment: Yep, I made a mistake. Just corrected it. The method should be a `function()`. It's only the ajax call that should be an arrow function. I'll also reformulate to be exact and specific, so it's helpful :)

Comment: That didn't do it either...how would I access the property "comments" with it being wrapped in a function?

Comment: OK sorry - I missed the fetchComments()

Comment: It's ok. You can either write it as `methods: { fetchComments() { ... }}` or `methods: { fetchComments: function() { ... }}`. It's exactly the same thing. I personally prefer the first syntax. For me, it's more readable but I'm aware it's a personal choice.

Comment: OK thanks so much. Curious, how would I get the list to re-load? Is there Vue/view method I can call? A quick Google suggests Vue.forceUpdate() to update my component, will this re-fetch the AJAX results?

Comment: You have two options: a) you throw away the app when you close the modal (and you create a new one next time you open it). b) you store the app in a variable and call its `.fetchComments()` when you re-open the modal, if the app has been created (and placed in the variable). In both options the `$.ajax` call is re-run.